# MySQL 'OR' not working

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to do this query:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM mail 
   WHERE tag_draft = 0 
     AND (target_id = 2 OR source_id = 2) 
GROUP BY created DESC`
```

...but it returns no rows. Now, if I do this query:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM mail 
   WHERE tag_draft = 0 
     AND target_id = 2 
GROUP BY created DESC
```

...then it works fine - every row with a `target_id` of 2 is selected. If I substitute `target_id` with `source_id`, it works fine too. The thing is, I want to select rows where the target **OR** source ID is 2 (2 used as an example here), however running the query first stated

(`SELECT * FROM mail WHERE tag_draft=0 AND (target_id=2 OR source_id=2) GROUP BY created DESC`)

, with or without inner brackets, returns no rows. I cannot figure out why this will not work, other than I'm doing something wrong with the OR bit.

Some example data:

```
source_id target_id etc_fields
-------------------------------
2         12        blah
12        2         blah
2         14        blah
2         10        blah
2         2         blah
```

All the above rows should be displayed in the table. what should NOT be displayed is stuff like:

```
source_id target_id etc_fields
-------------------------------
10        8         ...
255       16        ...
4         12        ...
```

Comment: Could you try formatting this a bit better?  Put your queries in their own paragraphs, indented 4 spaces (or select & click the `1010` button). This will make it properly formatted, coloured, and a LOT easier to read.

Comment: Can you provide your table definition and a few rows of example data that demonstrates the problem in a reproducible way?

Comment: this may sound dumb, but are you sure?

Comment: Any difference if you remove your GROUP BY clause ?

Comment: Is the query you posted the **exact** query you are running, or have you "simplified" it?

Comment: Ok, removing the GROUP BY clause sorts things out, but I need a way of selecting the most up to date row in a group of rows with the same thread ID, where either the source or target ID are (for example) 2

Comment: Do you have a primary key on the table, if so it's easy with a sub query.

Comment: yeah I have a unique ID field - I simplified the table somewhat for this post

Comment: The GROUP BY doesn't take ASC/DESC; I'm surprised you aren't getting a 1064 - syntax error for the query.

Comment: I should  definitely read the manual better lol - thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, assuming there's there's not more than one row with the same MAX(created) for the given condition:

```
SELECT m.* FROM mail m WHERE m.tag_draft=0 AND (m.target_id=2 OR m.source_id=2) AND
  m.created = (SELECT MAX(created) FROM mail sm 
       WHERE sm.tag_draft=0 AND (sm.target_id=2 OR smsource_id=2))
```

Or perhaps just

```
 SELECT m.id,m.target_id,m,m.source_id,MAX(created) FROM mail m 
    WHERE m.tag_draft=0 AND (m.target_id=2 OR m,source_id=2) 
  GROUP BY m.id,m.target_id,m.source_id
```

Make sure you GROUP BY every column that you select, except the aggregate ( MAX(created) ) , SELECT * won't do.

Comment: This looks promising, although I've been an idiot and not made my question clear enough :( What I have are 'threads', denoted by a thread_id column, which is the same for all rows in that thread. I also have the created date for the thread, again all the same. What is different, however, is the 'updated' field - that's unique. Would you be able to change your query to behave like I explained, or does it already?

Comment: Also, what does 'm.' and 'sm.' mean? are they different tables or something?

Comment: They're just aliases for the mail table. If the updated column is what you want, isn't it enough to use that column instead of the created column in the queries above ?

Comment: @nos - It could be, but I want to select the most up to date post from each thread, not the entire table, if you get me?

Comment: Somewhat, but this now deviates a lot from the original question. I suggest you post a new question with the actual table structures and what you want.